# Node.js application wont start on my public IP

Tags: reactjs, linux, network-programming, yarnpkg

I'm SSHing into a linux shell for a school project. Right now, we're trying to set up a react app for a web frontend. We were able to run the app on localhost easily enough, and all of the functionality seems to be good, but I can't figure out how to get this hosted on the public IP of the computer. We've been using yarn to do all of this, though i've tried other things, so here's some cli output.

```
path/to/thing# yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts start
Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: public.facing.ip.address        //This is a website name
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
Learn more here: //There was a link here but SO formatting wouln't let me keep it.

Could not find an open port at public.facing.ip.address.
Network error message: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available public.facing.ip.address  //numeric

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
root@computer:path/to/thing#
```

When I run hostname -I, public.facing.ip.address does not appear at all. So that seems like the obvious issue. The catch here is that we are also running jenkins on a separate port of public.facing.ip.address from this same computer. That was much easier to set up, it just came as something I could start as a service using 'systemctl start jenkins' and up it went onto the public facing IP. I set all that up and I can access it just fine, etc. The best I can do with this is modify the HOST variable either in the terminal or the .env file, then yarn starts a development server on localhost (which I can't access since I'm on a different network SSHing into this computer)

How do I make yarn host our webapp on the public facing IP?

Answer (score 0):

open your router page, there should be dmz host option somewhere, point it to your local ip address

Comment: Can't do that. We have to work through a university network, so all router configuration is controlled by them. They only barely let us have the two ports we need (one for jenkins, one for this site). I've tried hosting on the jenkins port as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

My networking inexperience was the culprit. Instead of using HOST=path.to.public.ip, the solution was to use HOST=0.0.0.0.